# Insert body within a body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have a page with 2 toggle buttons- "leaderboard" & "MedalTally" which looks like this:[image]

codes for above page:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">





  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">MedalTally</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">
          <h1>Display Leaderboard here</h1>
<!--
           Insert leaderboard codes here -->



        </div>

        <div id="login">
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

          <form action="/" method="post">

            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

          </form>

        </div>

      </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Again I have a leaderboard with the codes like this :

[image]

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/
.leaderboard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 308px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before, .leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
          transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DailyUI #019 - Leaderboard</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>


<div class="leaderboard">
  <h1>
    <svg class="ico-cup">
      <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
    </svg>
  Leaderboard
  </h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
      <small>315</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
      <small>301</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
      <small>292</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
      <small>245</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
      <small>245</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
  
  </ol>
</div>


<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
 C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
 C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
 c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
 c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
 c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
 c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
 c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
 c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
 c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
 C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
 c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
 L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
 c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
 C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
 C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
 c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
      </symbol>
</svg>




  </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that I want to insert the leaderboard (displayed in second pic) inside the ist picture at location "Display Leaderboard here" .

When the user clicks at the Leaderboard tag on the ist pic,the leaderboard should be visible and when he clicks at the MedalTally tag,MedalTally should be displayed.Please ignore the MedalTally part for time being.

Kindly help how do I solve the issue.

Comment: Add jquery function or use bootstrap tab for it.

Comment: you need tabs for this,  just google javascript tabs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use bootstrap tab or Js tabs or use custom jquery code.

Try This:
e.g.
Add an id attribute to leaderboard div, as given in Login div

```
<div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
```

hide leaderboard div and use custom jquery code:

```
$('.tab a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    if(block == "#leaderboard"){
        $(block).fadeIn();
        $('#login').hide();
    }
    if(block == "#login"){
        $(block).fadeIn();
        $('#leaderboard').hide();
    }
});
```

you can see here [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lcmedyk/) . I have use your code in Jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to achieve this before.jus want to know how do I bring the leaderboard  within the body of the leaderboard toggle button. M losing the shape  of the leaderboard here and its outside the body of the toggle buttons. Anyways,thanks for the support

Comment: remove position absolute from leaderboard div and set transform property to: transform: translate(0%, 0%);

Comment: thanks Zed,but why am I getting the counters repeated on the left.any suggestion to get rid of it..?

Comment: I think you are talking about counter 1,2,3,4,5,6.... on the left in leaderboard section, if so then remove "counter(leaderboard);" function from css, which is placed in ".leaderboard ol li::before".

Comment: @zed.Thank you for helping.But I want to get rid of the counter i.e 1,2,3... on the extreme left with black background.

Comment: add "overflow: hidden" to the ".leaderboard ol li small{ }".